# Menú despleable en bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un nav en mi web donde están todas las secciones, y allí es donde he aplicado un botón nuevo que manejará el uso de idiomas.

Todo funciona correctamente, pero visualmente el menú que debe desplegar los idiomas, no despliega fuera de su sección.

**¿Habría alguna forma de hacer un menú desplegable flotante o algo parecido?**

**¿Cómo puedo controlar esto para que el desplegable se vea completo sin límite de sección?**

Aquí dejo el código del nav, utilizo bootstrap 3.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/}"><img  class="img-responsive imagen" th:src="@{/images/Logo_web.jpg}"></a>
       </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav centro vista">
                        <li><a th:href="@{/about}" th:text="#{header.navbar.about}"></a></li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/shop}" th:text="#{header.navbar.shop}"></a></li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/list}" th:text="#{header.navbar.list}"></a></li>
                        <li sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')"><a th:href="@{/userslist}" th:text="#{header.navbar.userslist}"></a></li>
                        <li><a th:href="@{/gallery}" th:text="#{header.navbar.gallery}">Galer&iacute;a</a></li>
                        <li>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
                                type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
                                <span th:text="#{header.navbar.language}" th:remove="tag"></span>
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="?language=es">
                                        <p th:text="#{header.navbar.language.spanish}"></p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="?language=en">
                                        <p th:text="#{header.navbar.language.english}"></p>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right centro">
                            <li>
                                <a class="btn btn-success" th:href="@{/login}" th:text="#{header.navbar.login}"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right centro">
                            <li>
                                <a class="sesioniniciada"><span th:text="${#authentication.principal.nombre}"></span></a>
                                <a class="btn btn-info" th:href="@{/logout}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> <span th:text="#{header.navbar.logout}" th:remove="tag"></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN:
Este código está separado de los html, puesto que en mi proyecto dispongo de varios html.
Para que veais un ejemplo, esta es mi página html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title th:text="#{shop.title}"></title>
        <th:block th:insert="~{sections/head.html}"></th:block>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/script/funciones.js}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <th:block th:insert="~{sections/header.html}"></th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

El fichero donde esttá el código inicial, es el header.html.

Comment: el ejemplo que has dejado no es funcionañ, puedes agregar un sniped para ver que has intentado?

Comment: no entiendo esto que es: `th:href`

Comment: th:href es una etiqueta de thymeleaf. Esto está dentro de un archivo y desde otros ficheros html hago llamada al fichero donde está este código para insertarlo en la página

Comment: ok que raro por que las etiquetas html son solo href, pense que era algo de .net ...

Comment: borra la actualizacion, en la parte de abajo solo van respuestas/soluciones, no actualizaciones.